# Can cellulardata & WiFi be on while charging? Sporadic case of meager increase in charging while both were on

Tags: charging, connection-issues, internet

Last night cellular data & wifi were on. Previously IN THIS STATUS, my mobile charged 100%. Last night my mobile was in charging. To my surprise, I found charging had improved from 7% to 17% only. After this I turned off wifi & cellular data. NOW charging is improving slowly. Is this right solution? Any alternatives?

Answer (score 2):

The WiFi + Mobile data should not eat up so much energy that the charging is slow, except if you have an ancient phone/charging device that has no quick charge technologies.

I would suggest:

1. make sure you are charging from a wall charger (i.e. not from PC USB port) and try to use a quick charger (QC 3.0 or similar)
2. make sure your cable is of good quality (official, or some other, try different cables if charging is still slow)
3. make sure your phones CPU is not on and running all the time because of some background app/process. That is the only thing that could drain it faster than it charges.

Comment: +1. Deleted my answer, your answer makes more sense